# how to create object with return type of both 1) true/false and 2) dynamic data

Tags: c++

just as the return type of the method mysql_fetch_array() is both a boolean a numerative array and an associate array where you can assess if the sql query was successful and if so store the return data into an array and then access that same object $row and display the rows like shown:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    echo $row['name']. " - ". $row['age'];
    echo "<br />";
}
```

so you can both test the $row variable for true or false and then access the $row variable in this case being an array and be able to do things with it.

I'd like to do the same in c++

im trying to create a method that will return the enum value based on a few conditions within the method and if the method is true then do something else. The problem is i dont know how to create this data type. How can i achieve this?

Comment: I may not understand correctly, but `std::pair`?

Comment: what im trying to do is something like this

SomeSpecialDataType which contains data

if(SomeSpecialDataType temp = fooDoSomthingAndReturnData() then do something. so if the method returns true... it also returns the data along with it.... if the method returns false then the if statement is not executed

Comment: what im not sure about is how to create a data object which you can both ... test in logical expressions and also access data contained in them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is `std::pair`. It holds two values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

std::pair<bool, int> foo (int i)
{
    std::pair<bool, int> ret;

    if (i != 5)
    {
        ret.first = true;
        ret.second = i;
    }

    else
    {
        ret.first = false;
        ret.second = 0;
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    if (foo (6).first)
        std::cout << foo (6).second << '\n'; //prints

    if (foo (5).first)
        std::cout << foo (5).second; //doesn't print
}
```

Edit:
Ah, seeing as how this was my first time dealing with `std::pair`, I overlooked something. You could use `std::make_pair (true, i)` and return that to make for a less-cluttery function. Returning `std::pair<bool, int> (true, i)` should also work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Use a smart pointer:

```
while (std::shared_ptr< std::map<string, Variant> > row = fetch_row(result)) {
    std::cout << (*row)["name"] << " - " << (*row)["age"] << "\n<br />";
}
```

Make sure `fetch_row()` returns a pointer to a map if there's another row available, or the null pointer when it runs out of rows.

Comment: in this case you've done while(.... row = fetch_row){
// and then used that same row variable to grab the data out
}
how did you test that same variable inside a logical expression, how do you make it so that when you put the variable in a logical expression the while statement knows to test the boolean of that row variable?

Comment: @Pavan: That's just how `while` behaves. The construct `while (T x = f()) { … }` is roughly analogous to `{ T x; while ((x = f())) { … } }`, except that in the first case, `x` is a distinct variable in each pass of the while loop (and doesn't require a default constructor, for that matter). In the answer, `std::shared_ptr` can be tested by if/while/for and will pass if it holds something other than the null pointer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [boost optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html), which was designed for exactly this purpose:
Reworking chriss's code to use this would look something like this:

```
boost::optional<int> foo (int i)
{
    if (i != 5)
    {
        return boost::optional<int>(i);
    }

    else
    {
        return boost::optional<int>();
    }
}

int main()
{
    boost::optional<int> f6 = foo(6);
    if ( f6 )
        std::cout << *f6 << '\n'; //prints

    boost::optional<int> f5 = foo(5);
    if ( f5 )
        std::cout << *f5 << '\n'; //doesn't print
}
```

One benefit of this over using `std::pair<bool,X>` is that `boost::optional<X>` will work for types `X` without default constructors.